# How to implement indicator function in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanna implement a function like this:if x == k, f(x) = 1, else f(x) = 0(k is a parameter). So I used tf.equal and tf.cast and my code was like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = range(12)
a = tf.Variable(a)
b = 6
b = tf.Variable(b)
a = tf.reshape(a, [3, 4])

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
c = tf.equal(a, b)
d = tf.cast(c, tf.int32)
print sess.run(c)
print sess.run(d)
```

It seems fine, **but the problem is tf.gradients(d, a) and tf.gradients(d, b) are None.** I tried tf.gradients(c, a) and got TypedError. Are there any decent way to implement this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the gradient is even defined here.

The indicator function is f(a,b) = 1 if a=b, 0 otherwise. Away from a=b, this function is constant (zero) and so has zero derivative. At any point where a=b the function is discontinuous, so it doesn't have a derivative there.

More intuitively: derivatives don't exist where you have a 'jump' in your function.

Comment: I agree, but like max pooling and relu, I just want to back propagate the gradient to some variables

Comment: I see your point - it's true that the gradient for relu(x) is not defined at x=0. But it is defined on either side of that: d relu / dx = 1 for x > 0, and 0 for x < 0. And d max(x,y) / dx = 1 if x > y, 0 if x < y. It takes different (non-zero) values over most of the domain - and when doing discrete updates you're unlikely to actually hit x=0, or x=y. But in the case of the indicator function the derivative is zero everywhere that it's defined. Also, the indicator function itself is discontinuous.

Comment: I agree with @HarryBraviner that a jump introduce a discontinuity however there some way to get a derivative. (see [link#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Derivatives_of_the_indicator_function) and [link#2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_of_the_indicator#Dirac_surface_delta_function))
regarding the integration of a condition within tensorflow, why not using [cond(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) function ?

Comment: The Dirac delta function isn't really a function, certainly not from R -> R. I think technically it might be a distribution, in that it has an integral.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to have the PDF of the normal distribution to approximate the indicator function. I am also new to TensorFlow, so feel free to point out any issue.

```
##I am using tensorflow2
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
import tensorflow_probability as tfp 

a = tf.range(12)
a = tf.Variable(a)
b = 6
b = tf.Variable(b)
a = tf.reshape(a, [3, 4])

## Define the PDF of a normal distribution to approximate the indicator function
dist = tfp.distributions.Normal(0., 0.1)
scalar = dist.prob(0) # a normalization constant
#since the pdf at data zero is not one

## Implement the approximazed indicator function
a = tf.cast(a, dtype= tf.float32)
b = tf.cast(b, dtype= tf.float32)
c = dist.prob(a-b)/scalar
#d = tf.cast(c, tf.int32)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(c))

## calcualte the gradient
c_a = tf.gradients(c, a) 
print(sess.run(c_a))
```

Comment: It works in Tensorflow1. Then I also tried to implement in Tensorflow2, but it returns "none". Not sure the reason...